# Upgrade php to 5.4 on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, php

I want to upgrade php from 5.3.6 to 5.4 on ubuntu 11.10

According to some tutorials I did:

```
1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I also tried to remove php and install it again but I still have 5.3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- This PPA does not carry a Oneiric version of PHP. That's why installing it doesn't do anything.
- 11.10 is unsupported as of today. It's no longer going to get security updates, leaving it vulnerable. I strongly recommend upgrading to 12.04 which will be supported until April 2017.
- You'll need to install the PPA after you've upgraded to 12.04 (which still ships 5.3.x) but it should work then.